# Python - Using .format() on a JSON string that already has curly braces '{ }'

Tags: python-requests

I'm sending sending a multipart/form-data body in my POST request. There is already curly brackets in the request so I'm not sure how to use .format() on this string and preserve the existing brackets as part of the string ('{' located at index 104 and '}' located at index 146 in the payload below

For example, how would I insert the following dynamic content into the payload? {DATE}, {BATCH_NAME}, {FILE_NAME}, {PERSON_NAME_1}, etc.

```
payload = "--CHEESE\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"criteria\"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{\r\n    \"process_date\": \"{DATE}\"\r\n}\r\n--CHEESE\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{BATCH_NAME}\"; filename=\"{FILE_NAME.txt}\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n{FULL_NAME PERSON_1}\r\n{FULL_NAME_PERSON_2}\r\n{FULL_NAME_PERSON_3}\r\n--CHEESE--\r\n"
```

**What I tried**

I tried breaking down the payload into smaller string sections then concatenate them back together after inserting the content but it's a huge hassle.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use double brackets '**{{ }}**' where there are existing single brackets in the string.

Like so:

```
payload = "--CHEESE\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"criteria\"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{{\r\n    \"process_date\": \"{}\"\r\n}}\r\n--CHEESE\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{}\"; filename=\"{FILE_NAME.txt}\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n{FULL_NAME_PERSON_1}\r\n{FULL_NAME_PERSON_2}\r\n{FULL_NAME_PERSON_3}\r\n--CHEESE--\r\n".format(DATE,BATCH_NAME,FULL_NAME_PERSON_1,FULL_NAME_PERSON_2)
```